# How can I set the default Value on a custom SelectOption List?

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist, selectoption, default-value

The Following works good to retrieve my account list in a SelectList on my VF. 
 But I'm trying to set a specific Default Account as the first value in the list - Now it shows up last.. 
***Is there any way to choose a specific Value (based on any Criteria I choose) from my account List and set as Default on my SelectList ?? ***

Controller :

```
public List<Account> matchingAccounts          = new List<Account>();
public List<SelectOption> accountSelectOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
public String matchAccountId                 {get;set;}
public String accountName                    {get;set;}

public List<SelectOption> getAccountSelectOptions()     { 
    matchingAccounts = [Select Id,Name From Account WHERE Name LIKE : accountName];
    if(matchingAccounts!=null) {
         for(Account acc:matchingAccounts){
             if(acc.myDefault__c) {
             accountSelectOptions.add(new SelectOption(acc.Id, acc.Name));

             //Setting as Default Value - FIXED...
             matchAccountId =  acc.Id;
             }
             else {
              accountSelectOptions.add(new SelectOption(acc.Id, acc.Name));
             }
            } 
    else {
         accountSelectOptions.add(new SelectOption('New','New Account: '+pot.Account_Name__c));
          }
    return accountSelectOptions;
  }
```

VF Page :

```
<apex:selectList label="Account Name" value="{!matchAccountId}" size="1" required="true">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!accountSelectOptions}"/>
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="thePageBlock" action="{!showHideRTSelect}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Comment: Please see this other question: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yttIAA

Comment: (1) I'm surprised this VF page compiled - `matchAccountId` should be public; (2) the if-else in the for loop seems unnecessary as coded; (3) `matchingAccounts` will never be null as it is instantiated from a SOQL call and hence will be a list, possibly empty

Comment: Sorry late at night and I copied the playground code Not the actual so might be some mistakes.. (1) fixed it you are correct should be public since I need to call it from my VF (2) if-else was done in order to choose which value will be default (3) 'matchingAccounts' can be null as it always finds similar accounts by a given Name.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, set the default value on `matchAccountId`. The Select List should initialize with that value as selected.

Comment: True.. I have fixed the code above according to your answer - I think i it should work fine now. matchAccountId default Value was set inside if-else statement..

Answer (score 0):

For Visualforce there is a hacky solution available aswell:

```
<apex:selectOption value="foo" html-selected="true"/>
<apex:selectOption value="bar" />
```

The `html-selected="true"` is being set directly on the html option tag.
In HTML `selected` is used to define the standard option.
Note that is normally does not have an asigned value (="true")